# How do you handle promises on views and with watches - AngularJs 1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I took the approach of implementing all my properties and methods as returning promises, which i believe is the "angular" way.

I have also gone down the route of removing $scope from all controllers and directives and using the `controllerAs` and `bindToController` methods.

**1. Watches.**
Before i would watch a variable by doing something like this

```
var $removeWatch = $scope.$watch(function() {
    return _myService.myProperty(); 
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {

});
```

and my property in my service would be very basic, like so

```
this.myProperty = function() {
    return "myValue";
}
```

Now i have changed my property to use promises, so now it looks like so

```
this.myProperty = function() {
    var $defer = $q.defer();
    $defer.resolve("myValue");
    return $defer.promise;
}
```

But now my watch doesnt work?  How can i get my watch to work? Since i have removed scope everywhere, how can i watch a variable/property/method?

**2. Property From View**
In my html page, i would have something similar to this

```
<span ng-bind="::getName()"></span>
```

And my controller would have a method on it that looked similar to this.

```
$scope.getName = function() {
    return _myService.myProperty();
};
```

Now i have removed scope and changed my property to return promise (same property in the service example above), this no longer works.

How can i return data to my view from a property/method that uses promises?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do with theses promises. What is the benefit of returning all you vars as promises ? What do you try to do with your watch ? Using $watch is not recommended in angular. I guess you have a usecase for you $watch that could be done in a more "angular" way.

Comment: For your exemples : You need to handle the promise like this : _myService.myProperty().then(function(data){}) but you can't return a value from a promise resolve within an other function

Comment: These are very simple examples. Properties i have usually iterate through arrays etc, so have converted to promises and they may take a slight bit of time.  How can i handle watches in a more "angular" way?

Comment: In my opinion using watches isn't an angular way. The angular directives already use all the watch that could match your usecases. The uses of promises is legitimate. Could you provide an exemple without the promise in a plunker ? and a other plunker with your try ? (So that i can make the two plunker match)

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something here, but this is what I understood from the problem that you're experiencing:

If you're handling promises like this:

```
var ctrl = this; // controller

somePromise().then(function(data) {
  ctrl.someProperty = data;
})
```

Then you should be able to watch for ctrl.property change:

```
$scope.$watch(ctrl.someProperty, function (newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(newVal, oldVal);
})
```

Your view should be able to display the `ctrl.someProperty` data without any problem.

Of course previously suggested plunkers would be very helpful for more detailed solutions.

Hope this helps.